# mySQL complex SELECT with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

A mysql table has two date (timestamp) columns.

Only those rows with a date greater the current timestamp should be selected, ordered by the closest date (counted from the current timestamp).

Column "date_1" includes always a date value.

"date_2" includes always a later (higher) date value, but sometimes "date_2" ist not set with a date value (in this case, the timestamp of "date_2" is empty or zero, for example the following row with name "D"):

Example:

| name | date_1 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-03-29 | 2022-03-29 (1 year later) |
| B | 2021-11-15 | 2021-12-07 |
| C | 2021-11-24 | 2021-12-28 |
| D | 2021-11-25 | (empty) |

The following mysql code does not work correct (executed on 16/11/2021):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_1 > time() OR date_2 > time() ORDER BY date_1, date_2`

The (wrong) result order is:

| name | date_1 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | (2021-03-29, expired) | 2022-03-29 |
| B | (2021-11-15, expired) | 2021-12-07 |
| C | 2021-11-23 | 2021-12-28 |
| D | 2021-11-25 | (empty) |

Changing the order (ORDER BY date_2, date_1)...

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_1 > time() OR date_2 > time() ORDER BY date_2, date_1`

...results as follows (also wrong):

| name | date_1 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D | 2021-11-25 | (empty) |
| B | (2021-11-15, expired) | 2021-12-07 |
| C | 2021-11-23 | 2021-12-28 |
| A | (2021-03-29, expired) | **2022-03-29** |

The correct mySQL SELECT order executed on **2021-11-16** should be (the essential dates are formatted in bold):

| name | date_1 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | **2021-11-23** | 2021-12-28 |
| D | **2021-11-25** | (empty) |
| B | (2021-11-15, expired) | **2021-12-07** |
| A | (2021-03-29, expired) | **2022-03-29** |

The correct mySQL SELECT order executed for example on **2021-11-24** should be:

| name | date_1 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D | **2021-11-25** | (empty) |
| B | (2021-11-15 expired) | **2021-12-07** |
| C | (2021-11-23, expired) | **2021-12-28** |
| A | (2021-03-29 expired) | **2022-03-29** |

The correct mySQL SELECT order executed for example on **2021-12-08** should be:

| name | date_1 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | (2021-11-23, expired) | **2021-12-28** |
| A | (2021-03-29 expired) | **2022-03-29** |

How should the correct SELECT statement look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do that by selecting a new column using an `IF` statement and then `ORDER BY` that new column. Like so

```
SELECT *, IF(date_1 > DATE(NOW()), date_1, date_2) as NewDate 
FROM table 
WHERE date_1 > DATE(NOW()) OR date_2 > DATE(NOW()) 
ORDER BY NewDate
```

[Check this fiddle out](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/34aXtuVXFScDQJavjGKbMi/0)